# PostgreSQL: How to iterate over a list of table and perform updates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning PostgreSQL and I have stumbled over a very basic requirement. 
I want to iterate over an array of table and update a specific column (the column name is same in all these tables). My idea is to hold these table names in an array and use a for loop to iterate over each table and update the column.

This is what I have done so far:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  old_value varchar := 'old_value';
  new_value varchar := 'new_value';

  affected_table_names  TEXT[] := '{"table_1", "table_2"}';

BEGIN
  FOREACH tableName IN affected_table_names
    LOOP

      update tableName
      set column_name = old_value
      where column_name = new_value;

  END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

However, when I execute this pgAdmin4, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "affected_table_names"
LINE 25:   FOR tableName IN affected_table_names
                                ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "affected_table_names"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 836
```

I am not sure what needs to be done to fix the error. I know it's syntax error, because it says so in here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/errcodes-appendix.html

Could anybody please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and build up a string containing your query. The table-name (or any column-names etc) are not part of the "varying" part of the query. You could use any random text and the query might / might not work - the query planner can't figure out its "shape".

It is good practice to use the `quote_ident` function as shown in the example on that page.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this out.

Comment: Table name is varying. As you can see, it varies because it's stored in an array and is iterated over it. Column names do not vary though